# HtmlUnit vk authorization

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am new in Html Unit , I am trying to enter in the vk site , but each time it doesn't want to enter on this site. I saw a couple of tutorial , there is almost the same code , with this code , I've entered to 
https://news.ycombinator.com/

Here is my code;

```
import java.util.logging.*;

import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class ContactApp {

public static WebClient login(String url , String login , String password) throws Exception {
    // create webClient
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    //open logger
    loggingAll();

    // options for loggers 
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    // setting all configuration
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    HtmlForm htmlForm = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"login_form\"]");
    HtmlInput loginInput = htmlForm.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"email\"]");
    HtmlInput passwordInput = htmlForm.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"pass\"]");

    // set login and password attribute
    loginInput.setValueAttribute(login);
    passwordInput.setValueAttribute(password);
    HtmlButton buttonClick = htmlForm.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"login_button\"]");

    htmlForm = buttonClick.getEnclosingForm();
    HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage(htmlForm.getWebRequest(null));
    return webClient;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String url = "https://vk.com/login";
    String username = "login";
    String password = "password";

    System.out.println("Start !!!");

    WebClient webClient = login(url , username , password);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://vk.com/mypage");

    // I am checking getting a name to my page by xpath;
    String entering = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"page_info_wrap\"]/div[1]/h2");

    // Entering to the site // 
    // He always send me - null in text; 
    System.out.println(entering);

    System.out.println("End!!!");
}
```

}

This is my logic; Thank you;

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna login to https://vk.com/mypage u need to adjust the XPath , becuase it has different html and different ids. So as an example the html form on this very site has the id "quick_login_form". Press F12 in your firefox then go to inspect tab. You can there see the html and the ids of the html dom items.

Comment: This is not about mypage and etch , I try to check whether I enter to the site or not , and why my code is does not authorize in this site. There is a problem , not problem of extacting id from html.

Comment: Well what site are u trying to enter then and whats etch

Comment: Vk.com , I made a mistake with "etc" ;